# Problem about a process with bins of balls

Tags: recreational-mathematics

A friend of mine give me this problem for fun:

Given $\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$ balls, first we divide *arbitrarily* these balls in baskets, after that we make another basket with one ball of each basket e do this procedure infinitely.

I want to prove that one time this stabilizes with 1 ball in one basket, 2 balls in another basket, ..., n balls in another basket.

It seems easy to solve, he says we can use some concept of energy (???), I'm trying with some concepts of combinatorics without any success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. You second paragraph where you explain what you do with the balls is unfortunately not clear (at least to me). How many baskets are there? How do you divide the balls into baskets?, etc.

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title.

Comment: It sounds like you have $n$ baskets and distribute the balls in any way.  Then you have another set of $n$ baskets.  Into the first basket of the second set you put one ball from each of the first set of baskets that has one.  Then into the second basket of the second set you put one ball from each of the first set that still has one, and keep going.  Now repeat the process from the second set into the first.  Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: @RossMillikan Then, the problem is, if, in the initial configuration, there were the entire $n(n+1)/2$ balls in the first basket of the first set, and none in the others, we do not run out of all the balls in the first basket of the first set of baskets after only "one pass." In fact, in this case the system will oscillate.

Comment: user85493, you're really going to have to explain this better.

Comment: @LordSoth the number of basket is arbitrary.

Comment: @RossMillikan the initial condition is with an arbitrary number of baskets

Comment: Then, as Lord Soth says, if the number of baskets is at least $n(n+1)/2$ and we start with all the balls in one basket, after one move we have one ball each in $n(n+1)/2$ baskets and we oscillate.  What you are trying to prove is then false.

Comment: I've edited the title to at least slightly reflect the content - 'Interesting Problem' says nothing useful about the question.  Feel free to edit it further, obviously, but I definitely recommend giving at least some description of the problem in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you are discussing is known as [Bulgarian solitaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_solitaire). This is a theorem of Jorgen Brandt, i.e., that the game ends as you have described when the number of balls (or cards) is a triangular number,  i.e., of the form $n(n+1)/2$.

---

Here is a nice source to read over: (paywall)

Solution of the Bulgarian Solitaire Conjecture

Kiyoshi Igusa

Mathematics Magazine

Vol. 58, No. 5 (Nov., 1985), pp. 259-271

Published by: Mathematical Association of America

Article Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690174

---

Note this is also the subject of a problem in the June/July 2013 AMM: Problem 11712.

Comment: This is exactly what I presume the OP was talking about.  Very nicely done.

Comment: Thanks; was just lucky to recognize it from glancing at the most recent AMM.

Comment: No problem. If you can get a hold of the most recent issue of the American Mathematical Monthly (June/July '13) you (or your friend) might check out the problem on Bulgarian solitaire.

Comment: I didn't find this problem in the magazine of june/july '13, what's the name of the article?

Comment: Check the Problems and Solutions section of AMM June/July 2013 and look at the first problem listed (i.e., AMM Problem 11712).